# SWIG typedef recognition

Tags: swig, typedef

I am trying too use my C++ class in PHP. in my C++ code I have declared the typedef as:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

so I intended to let SWIG consider my typedef in wrapper class, my interface file is something like this:

```
%module xxx

typedef unsigned char byte;

%include "xxx.h"

....

%{

typedef unsigned char byte;

#include "xxx.h"

%}
```

and in my test code I refer to type as:

```
byte *data;
```

but I've got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'unsigned_char' not found in xxx.php
```

P.S: I also include "stdint.i" in my interface file but got the same error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the interface you've shown is viable and works for simple cases, e.g. I wrote the following header file to test:

```
byte *make() { return NULL; }
void consume(byte *data) {}
```

And used the interface:

```
%module xxx

typedef unsigned char byte;

%include "xxx.h"

%{
typedef unsigned char byte;

#include "xxx.h"
%}
```

Which I was able to compile and test with the following PHP:

```
<?php
include("xxx.php");
$r = xxx::make();
xxx::consume($r);
?>
```

and it worked as expected.

A few points to note from that though:

1. In general I would be inclined to write the code you want passed through to the module (i.e. the bits inside the `%{ %}` before your `%include`.
2. Rather than using your own typedef for `byte` I'd be inclined to use one of the standard int types, e.g. `uint8_t`
3. It's not clear from your question quite how you intend to use `byte *data` - presumably it's an array in which case you'll want to [add a little more code](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_carrays) to your interface. (Or better still use `std::vector<byte>` since it's C++):

   ```
   %module xxx

   %{
   typedef unsigned char byte;

   #include "xxx.h"
   %}

   %include <carrays.i>

   %array_class(byte,ByteArray);

   typedef unsigned char byte;

   %include "xxx.h"
   ```

   Which can then be used in PHP as:

   ```
   $a = new ByteArray(100);
   $a->setitem(0, 1);
   $a->setitem(1, 2); //...
   xxx::consume($a->cast());
   ```

   `ByteArray` is a utility class provided by SWIG to hold and wrap a raw C array of `byte`s.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it works fine now, I had a mistake in PHP code and my byte type is recognized by PHP.