# SWIG (Java): How can I call a function with a void* out parameter?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig, void-pointers

**Background**

I am developing a real-time communication app for Android using a C++ code library. I generate a JNI bridge using SWIG to access the native code from Java. In order to keep track of an active call, a `void*` is used as a handle (which points to an adress containing information about the ongoing call). The following function headers are examples of how it is meant to be used:

`void initiateCall(void** callHandleRef);`

`void closeCall(void* callHandle);`

`initateCall` takes a `void**`, allocates a struct and writes its address (as a void*) to `callHandleRef`. It works as an "out" parameter in that you pass it as an argument and expect something to be written to it. When `closeCall` is called, the raw pointer is passed, allowing the C++ library to access the data associated with that specific call.

**Problem description**

I want to invoke `initiateCall` and `closeCall` from Java, using SWIG to generate the JNI code necessary to do so. However. SWIG generates types "SWIGTYPE_p_p_void" and "SWIGTYPE_p_void" respectively, and I am unable to use these in the way described above. How to I setup my SWIG interface file to allow me to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to declare the parameter with [OUTPUT as name](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Arguments_nn5)? You probably want to use a type alias for void so you can automatically call the destructor too.

Comment: I think my answer to a previous questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739331/swig-interface-to-receive-an-opaque-struct-reference-in-java-through-function-ar/12767656#12767656 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360180/168175 should cover your use case too

Comment: @Flexo thank you, the second answer you linked worked very well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexo's comment on the question turned out to work for me, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360180/168175). This is my solution, more or less copy-pasted from their answer.

C++ header (call.h):

```
typedef void* CALL_HANDLE;

int initiateCall(const char* name, CALL_HANDLE* handle);
int closeCall(CALL_HANDLE handle);
```

SWIG interface (call.i):

```
%module bridge

%include <cpointer.i>

%pointer_class(CALL_HANDLE, inst_ptr);
%javamethodmodifiers initiateCall "private";
%pragma(java) modulecode=%{
  public static SWIGTYPE_p_void initiateCall(String name) {
      inst_ptr ptr = new inst_ptr();
      final int err = initiateCall(name, ptr.cast());
      if (0 != err) {
          // Throw error or something like that
      }
      return ptr.value();
  }
%}

%include "include/call.h"

extern int initiateCall(const char* name, CALL_HANDLE* handle);
extern int closeCall(CALL_HANDLE handle);
```

Main activity (MainActivity.kt):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var callHandle: SWIGTYPE_p_void

    fun call(name: String) {
        callHandle = bridge.initiateCall(name)
    }

    fun hangup() {
        bridge.closeCall(callHandle)
    }
}
```