# How to access value of struct that only has pointer typedef with SWIG/Python

Tags: c, python-2.7, swig

I am creating a Python wrapper for an existing code base with a DLL and header.  I am using SWIG.

The code base has multiple struct pointer defs like so:

```
typedef struct session* session_t;
```

In this example, `session` is not defined anywhere else.  All other functions in the DLL take `session_t` as an input. If I try and reference `session` anywhere in SWIG generated code I get compile errors that `session` is not defined.  I need a way to access the value of `session_t` in Python code.

I've tried using cpointer.i and pointer_functions macro, but this doesn't work since it assumes the input type is not a pointer.

I thought if I could redefine the struct:

```
typedef struct Session {} session, *session_t;
```

This could work, but I cant find a way to do this with SWIG.

Is there a way to access the value of a struct pointer with SWIG if it's only definition is a typdef struct pointer?

Edit:  possible fix is the SWIG `%ignore` directive.  Might be able to ignore the original struct def and replace it in the .i file.

Solved(ish): I marked Mark Tolonen's answer as correct since it has a lot of useful relevant information.   The API I'm trying to wrap has a lot of deleted constructors and behaviors locking down how it's used.  I ended up writing a C++ wrapper in it's own namespace then telling Swig to ignore everything except my namespace.  I then only use standard or my own types to interface with Swig/Python.

Comment: A possible workaround is to complete the structure declaration, e.g. put `struct session {};` somewhere in the header file. This way, you must also ensure that you never allocate a `struct session` by yourself.

Comment: You need a factory function like `session_t session_open(void)` which returns a new instance of `session_t` (like e.g. `fopen`).

Comment: I anticipate that you have some function, which creates a `session*` and perhaps other functions, which use `session*`. Take a lot at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478649/how-to-apply-swig-output-typemaps-for-class-types-in-python/39045546#39045546 The base class can be replaced with a simple `typedef` to make it more C like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWIG works very well with opaque types.  Here's a full example where I've provided the source for a `test.dll` that uses an opaque typedef.  The structure is only defined within the `.c` file and SWIG has no knowledge of the definition.  If you are still having a problem update your question with a reproducible example.  I suspect you've used `session` instead of `session_t` in some typemap, but without a reproducible example I can only show that it works without a definition.

**test.c**

```
#define API_EXPORTS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

struct session {
    int a;
};

API session_t alloc(void) {
    session_t s = malloc(sizeof(session_t));
    if(s)
        s->a = 123;
    return s;
}

API int get_a(session_t s) {
    return s->a;
}

API void release(session_t s) {
    free(s);
}
```

**test.h**

```
#ifdef API_EXPORTS
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef struct session* session_t;

API session_t alloc(void);
API int get_a(session_t s);
API void release(session_t session);
```

**test.i**

```
%module test
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "test.h"
```

**test session**

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> s = test.alloc()
>>> test.get_a(s)
123
>>> test.release(s)
>>>
```

Comment: I had this in mind as well, but I think OP is asking how to get a `session_t` without an `alloc` function, i.e. something like for C++ classes where you can get an instance using `test.Class()`.

Comment: @Henri A DLL that uses an opaque pointer without a way to obtain one? That makes no sense, but the OP is free to clarify.

Comment: Yeah this is a combination of less than idea DLL src and me not being a C expert. Since session_t is a pointer does sizeof(session_t) give the size of a pointer or the structure it's pointing to?

Comment: @Geordie `sizeof(session_t)` gives the size of the pointer.  I would expect some API of the DLL to be something like `OpenSession()` and return a `session_t` somehow, similar to my demo with `alloc()`.