# C++ destructor not being called in a swig interface file

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am creating an interface between c++ and python code.

I create a module called `composition_api` in a swig interface file. It has methods that I import into a python module as shown below.

```
/// SWIG Interface File.
%module composition_api
%{
    #include <include/mcm/compiler/compilation_unit.hpp>


    mv::CompilationUnit* getCompilationUnit(bool disableHardware)
    {
        auto unit = new mv::CompilationUnit("pySwigCU");
             return unit;
    }
}
```

I import this as library into a python script.

Python script

```
import composition_api as ca
compUnit = ca.getCompilationUnit(not enableHardware)
```

When the python script is finished running the `CompilationUnit` destructor is not being called in the C++ source code. Do I have to create a method in the interface file that calls `delete unit`?

Answer (score 0):

The C++ counterpart of `compUnit` is a pointer. When `compUnit` is garbage collected by Python, it simply garbage collects the pointer. It does not automatically call `delete` on the pointer.

You have couple of choices that I can think of.

1. Return an object to Python that is wrapper to the pointer. When the object gets garbage collected, its destructor will be called. Add the necessary code to delete the C++ object in the destructor of the wrapper.
2. Add an explicit function in the swig interface file to delete the object. Make sure to call the function in Python before the scope of the Python object ends.

Comment: @R Sahu thank you for your suggestions, I will try number 2. If you have time could you describe how you would do option 1?

Comment: For option 2, you can follow the guideline here, which ensures proper deletion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478649/how-to-apply-swig-output-typemaps-for-class-types-in-python/39045546#39045546